# Are there any known compatibility issues between Bootstrap theme and Panels Bootstrap Layouts module?

Tags: panels, theming

Officially, the [Drupal Bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_bootstrap_layouts) includes Panels in a [list of modules not officially supported](http://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs%21FAQ.md/group/faq/7).

There's a module, [Panels Bootstrap Layout](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_bootstrap_layouts), which claims to work with and recommends the Drupal Boostrap theme (as opposed to just hand-rolling Bootstrap). Its 7 branch is actively maintained but hasn't had a full release for a year or two.

Are there any compatibility issues between the two? In the module's issue queue, I found [a post from one user in Jan 2016 saying](https://www.drupal.org/node/2646916) they personally hadn't had any problems, but nothing more than this one post.

> The bootstrap maintainers warn that there may be incompatibility with this module. Although the bootstrap theme is recommended. It would be great if this were considered among the "supported" modules or specific caveats were identified. I've not found any specific issues ...

I've tried looking for open (or, fixed but not committed to stable) issues in both issue queues, not found anything but that doesn't mean there isn't anything.

Comment: You should look for my module [Zonepanels] (https://www.drupal.org/project/zonepanels). This module allow you easy create dynamic Panels layout with bootstrap.

Comment: I use them both together all the time. When they say not officially supported, they probably mean don't post issues on their issues queue about thing related panels layout module.